# Reuable typescript input components causes issues due to size param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a reusable React Typescript input component. One of the params for the component is "size" however its already used for input and I would like to overwrite it if possible.

So currently I have it setup like this:

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';

type IInputProps = {
  name?: string;
  size?: 's' | 'm';
  status?: '' | 'disabled' | 'invalid';
} & React.ComponentPropsWithRef<'input'>;

const Input = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, IInputProps>(
  ({ name, size = 'm', status = '', ...rest }: IInputProps, ref) => {
    const inputClassNames = classNames(
      'text-dark w-full ring-2 rounded-full py-1.5 px-3 tracking-wider dark:bg-bright',
      {
        'ring-transparent hover:ring-cyan hover:dark:ring-bright/10 focus-within:outline-none focus-within:border-none focus:ring-cyan':
          status !== 'invalid',
        'ring-transparent border-1 border-amber-600 focus-within:outline-none ':
          status === 'invalid',
        'h-12': size === 'm',
        'text-sm h-10': size === 's',
        'opacity-50': status === 'disabled',
      },
    );

    return (
      <div className='w-full'>
        <input ref={ref} id={name} name={name} className={inputClassNames} {...rest} />
      </div>
    );
  },
);

Input.displayName = 'Input';

export default Input;
```

Now typescript is complaining about size with this issue:
`TS2322: Type  string  is not assignable to type  never`

[image]

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `omit` the `size` property from `ComponentPropsWithRef` to overwrite it with your own `size` property.

```
type IInputProps = {
  name?: string;
  size?: 's' | 'm';
  status?: '' | 'disabled' | 'invalid';
} & Omit<React.ComponentPropsWithRef<'input'>, 'size'>;
```

**[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=56&pln=4&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBm0A7ilACbL5wC%20BUEIcA5FKhkwNwBQokscaADYoAziIByKEEhF0GzIaJEA7KTM5cuMAJ5gkcAJIHlYAK4wACvTCyAvLi5w4q6QH4AXHBEwowZQHNuJxFgAC8kD2YRJjgAH2YQDWCYFBhTEUimGPimMmARFAAjQSQybOY-ADcUQWAy7loAMjgAeRBgGAAeZHQYADoAYQZIZSRlS2sRAHUOgAtKTqY-MxgmAD5sJhDw9e4uNAhlb0MTczh7QigScgWACQAVAFkAGWMVgFES6XHsI1OJiA2NYACkccGBeBcSGw2309iYiRhKTSdmYTGwfUxrGO1E8fxWVkBImwrHwAEpzmsHE4nAcjvBluYBsIxJJpKjFKy1CJQTSaUwYEgAB4wAC0ZFIAGs4ERRfhTIJBHBfAFRQAmZUQUzKMilOUKpVgbSigCMfQArHAwELRQBmOA%20dCSvz%20UVEOpIKBwCVQSXuQquwq%20fyzVaYMF8nARvnMFWux1HMCkMbwWYQSqe9xx0VobQoZRwNMZqDuH1%207NB4AhmAAehNAAYCBA0Ok3XM-O4tTBaqNRcpDvpCC2RG2YLMO4VoLqoH2B03h1mXTm88omO5ozGvMj0nAAIS2eFVGp1dEb-nZhMiJOscZwSfkT2mu9Tx9SQqPgBs9cbQ9b7rHHZdj2SCzqMzDrpufLeKkO4HoeyjVLUZThpBzCzKaaprl4YRwgeCSnqhArCmKIiMOhDZYbC5x4VsBGQUwgLoB0xrmvWlHbnYNF5AUxSlHRfLUChNJknsfKsGkUAFryMadHklQCCyEhqLYTCyvKirrGeTidIy8CkrYOCkrQdQGVCtBQqZai0JySnSAZunMkobIyLQOCYn02IwLQNZrGenQ1nJvl8iJYKCVwIlAA)**

Comment: Ah i never knew about that! works, thanks!